# Determine when File was Copied to a Directory in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

**Problem:**

On Windows XP the following code allowed me to determine if a file had been recently copied to a certain directory (written or overwritten) at some point on the current day.

**Behaviour in Win XP:**

If the file was written or overwritten in the directory on the current day, "LastAccessTime" would return a date on the current day.

**Behaviour in Windows 7:**

It returns the date listed under "Accessed" in the file properties (i.e. via explorer).

**Notes:**

- ***When I use LastWriteTime*** it returns the "Modified" date shown in the file properties, which is not necessarily the date that the file was copied or overwritten in the current directory.

**Code:**

```
DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day,0,0,0);
FileInfo a = new FileInfo("file.txt");
if (a.LastAccessTime > today)
{//do something
}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, you might want to look at `DateTime.Today` :)

Comment: "However, this does not seem to work in Windows 7" - What do you mean by "this does not seem to work"? Do you get any exceptions/error codes/unexpected behavior/etc.?

Comment: Is this the exact code? I.e. is the file name relative (no path and just the name)? If yes, it can be that the current directory for the process is different from the one you expected.

Comment: @In silico: Good question. I updated the question above.

Comment: Running "fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1" will "break" it on XP and if you use 0 on NT6 it will be "fixed"

Comment: I've never tested it, and a quick google was inconclusive.  However, I've always assumed that LastAccessTime would be updated when a file was *read*.  Wouldn't this create false-positives?

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Windows Vista, last access time is not updated by default. This is to improve file system performance. You can find details here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx

However, you're not interested in LastAccessTime, you're interested in LastWriteTime.

```
FileInfo a = new FileInfo(f);
if (a.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Today)
{
    //do something
}
```

BTW - Note DateTime.Today. It produces the same result as your "today" code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test for *writing* you should use `LastWriteTime`. For example, this code writes out all the files which have been modified today:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(".").GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.LastWriteTime >= today)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I concur that `LastAccessTime` in Windows 7 seems not to be updated - I'm not sure why. This appears to be part of the file system though - looking at the directory with

```
dir /Ta
```

I see the same results as when I use `LastAccessTime`. Perhaps an update disabled updating the file system info on access.

Comment: It´s default disabled to save resources. Check out http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/

Comment: Updating of LastAccessTime was disabled by default starting in Windows Vista to improve NTFS performance. http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx

Comment: Anyone ever benchmarked to see how much gain you get in real life with these ntfs tunings?

Comment: @Mikael: If you're using an SSD, it's not just performance - you really don't want all those extra pointless writes wearing your disk.

Comment: That´s the best answer I ever got for those tweaks. And I am using SSD :) And Win7, so I guess I´m in the clear since I haven´t turned things back on.

Answer (score 1):

You say written/overwritten so you should use `LastWriteTime` not `LastAccessTime`.

[edit]

And LastAccessTime seems to be default disabled in Win7 in order to save resources. Check out http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/ on how to enable it.